# How create/redefine document command where command name is variable?

Tags: errors, luatex, expl3, xparse

This question connected with question about tagging of sections. I found solution,how to do it,but i dont know,how create/redefine document command,if command is argument of some other command. When i try to redefine it,i get an error:

LaTeX3 Error: First argument of '\RenewDocumentCommand' must be a command.

Help me please fix this. Also i have some doubts:

1. Should i use [{##2}] or simple [##2] for the second argument.
2. should i use {##3} or simple ##3 for third argument? Thanks everybody for any help.

```
\RequirePackage[patches]{pdfresources}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{pdfversion=2.0}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,uncompress,activate-all,add-new-tag=Title/P,interwordspace=true}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn{\g__sections_prop}{chapter=H1,section=H2,subsection=H3,subsubsection=H4}
\prop_map_inline:Nn \g__sections_prop{
\cs_set_eq:cc{orig@#1}{#1}
\RenewDocumentCommand #1{s o m}{
\tagstructbegin{tag=#2}
\tagmcbegin{tag=#2}
\use:x{
\exp_not:c {orig@#1}
\IfValueT {##1} { ##1 }
\IfValueT {##2} { [{##2}]}
{##3}
}

\tagmcend
\tagstructend
}
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\author{Alexandr Kozlovskiy}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Title}
\tagmcbegin{tag=Title}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\section{test}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
new test
\tagmcend
\tagstructend

\section{new test}

\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
new test again
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have not given much information and your points 1 and 2 do not obviously follow from the question in the title. `\expandafter\RenewDocumentCommand\csname \myvariable\endcsname....`   is one answer, that will redefine`\section if  `\myvariable` expands to `section`

Comment: @David carlisle ok,but how write \expandafter\RenewDocumentCommand\csname \myvariable\endcsname,using expl3 functions,and whether it will works for \renewdocumentcommand #1{args}{code}

Comment: @david carlisle I forgot insert code. Now i did it.

Comment: in case that this is meant for pdflatex too: your tagging commands are in the wrong places, they will affect the spacing around sectioning commands and introduce unwanted breakpoints. You can not even be sure that the begin-MC is on the same page as the end marker.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Ok,how you suggest to fix it,i mean what commands i should redefine or what checks i should do to avoid brakepoints. I know,you probably will not help me with coding of it,but help me with idea,how i can to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing this is what you want to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

% let's declare two commands
\newcommand{\testcmda}{}
\newcommand{\testcmdb}{}

% declare a variable to store command name
\newcommand{\cmdname}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% a function to renew commands
\newcommand{\myrenew}[2]{
    \exp_args:Nc \RenewDocumentCommand{#1}{m}{
        \par my~name:~#1
        \par args~2~from outer:~#2
        \par args~1~from~inner:~##1
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\cmdname}{testcmda}
\myrenew{\cmdname}{a}
\testcmda{b}
% you can type variable name directly as well
\myrenew{testcmda}{c}
\testcmda{d}

\renewcommand{\cmdname}{testcmdb}
\myrenew{\cmdname}{e}
\testcmdb{f}

\end{document}
```

If you want to know more about LaTeX3, you can refer to a tutorial [here](https://www.alanshawn.com/latex3-tutorial/).

Comment: It is impossible to diagnose the problem if you do not share your code somewhere.

Comment: I edited my question and inserted forgotten code.

Comment: Now,i hope,code here.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Did you use `\exp_args:Nc` in your code?

Comment: Yes,but as i wrote before,i get an error. Now you can see my code and add it,to sure in it,after adding \exp_args.

Comment: How to create new documentcommand with #1,because exp_args:Nc not works for me and why three members,as i understood,vote to close my question?

Comment: So,as i understood,exp_args not works for my code. Whether error,when i use #number as name of my command  xparse issue,which i should report to github?

Comment: I am providing some generic advice on macro expansion. As I am no expert on `pdfresources` package, I cannot provide more assistance on this issue. Regarding the status of this question, well, as you can see, you earn big bucks if you are good at Python/AI/Java etc, but no one is gonna get a  job by mastering LaTeX. Therefore, TeX.SE is somehow more purely driven by enthusiasm. When I ask questions, I always reformat my code and statement so that my question is as short and concise as possible, and my example is as readable as possible. Because it does not scare people's enthusiasm away.

Comment: I have been postponing reading `expl3` documentation for a long time. Glad that I looked at this post and came across with your tutorial. It's more user friendly and succinct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem,and here my code. I am not understood,why for * argument ifvalue command not fail,even without *,but for [] it's failed. @ulrike-fischerhow in your opinion i can fix situation with unwanted spaces around the sections?

```
\RequirePackage[patches]{pdfmanagement}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{pdfversion=2.0}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,uncompress,activate-all,add-new-tag=Title/P,interwordspace=true}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn{\g__sections_prop}{section=H2,subsection=H3,subsubsection=H4}
\prop_map_inline:Nn \g__sections_prop{
\cs_set_eq:cc{orig@#1}{#1}
\exp_args:No\RenewDocumentCommand {\cs:w #1 \cs_end:}{s o m}{
\tagstructbegin{tag=#2}
\tagmcbegin{tag=#2}
\use:x{
\exp_not:c {orig@#1}
\IfBooleanT {##1} { * }
\IfValueT {##2} { [##2]}
{##3}
}
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
}
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\author{Alexandr Kozlovskiy}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Title}
\tagmcbegin{tag=Title}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\section{test}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
new test
\tagmcend
\tagstructend

\section{new test}

\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
new test again
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
\end{document}
```